# import datatable in parceljs

Tags: datatables, parceljs

I'm trying to import the [datatables](https://datatables.net) (along with jquery and moment) with [parceljs](https://parceljs.org/).

I've used the workaround in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47984928/3380951) to import jquery.

Here are my files:

In index.html:

```
      <table id="tableFlows" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

in index.js:

```
import "./styles.scss";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";

import './workaround/import-jquery';
import './workaround/import-moment';

import 'moment-timezone';
import "tempusdominus-bootstrap-4";

import 'datatables.net-dt';

import "./flows.js";
```

In the console, i'm seeing this error:
[image: error in console]

The error comes from `flows.js`:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();

$('#buttonGo').on('click', function() {
  const moment1 = $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker('date');
  const moment2 = $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker('date');

  console.log(moment1.format('X'), moment2.format('X'));
});

$("#tableFlows").DataTable();
```

Please help.

Comment: [NPM section](https://datatables.net/download/index) in datatables document use `require`, but it does not work either.

Comment: related: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js, use `require( 'datatables.net-dt' )();` instead of your `import`