# How do I use Bootstrap 4 with Parcel on the client side of my app?

Tags: express, bootstrap-4, pug, bower, parceljs

Per Bower's site they recommend using Parcel for the frontend. In the past I've done this with Bower as:

```
npm install -g bower
```

In my app.js I tell Express the location of the client side:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

In the *.bowerrc* @ root level it includes:

```
{
  "directory":"public/bower_components"
}
```

and in the terminal I run `bower i bootstrap` and `bower i jquery`.

Results are:

```
/application
  /models
  /node_modules
  /public
    /bootstrap
    /jquery
  /views
    index.pug
  .bowerrc
  app.js
  package.json
```

in pug I'm calling Bootstrap as:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title #{title}
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
  body
    block content
    br
    hr
```

How can this be done in [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) instead of Bower? All I was able to find from my research was: "[How do I use jQuery and jQuery-ui with Parcel (bundler)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968529/how-do-i-use-jquery-and-jquery-ui-with-parcel-bundler)" Cannot find any results in the documentation of Parcel.